# Arrow spinning and tip rotating toward the terrain

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm making an arrow, I'm able to make it spin and rotate, but not at the same time. To rotate it (so that the tip points down) I've used this code:

```
 transform.LookAt(transform.position + rigidbody.velocity);
```

Or this other one:

```
 transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, rigidbody.velocity.normalized, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
```

They both works in rotating the arrow toward the terrain.

To spin it I use this code:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, rotatioSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Unfortunately, if it rotates it doesn't spin, the spin code is placed after the rotation code but the arrow spin only if I comment out the latter.

I'm new to Unity, do you have any idea on how to make it rotate and spin at the same time independently?

Comment: This probably will make no difference but what happens if you put the spin code before the rotation code?

Comment: @JohnOdom as you said, no difference :(

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can try

```
transform.Rotate(transform.forward, rotatioSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World); // <--- transform.forward maybe?
```

What i would do though is put the arrow inside of a parent empty `GameObject` that way you can rotate the parent for the direction of the arrow, and then rotate the arrow itself around its own axis independently and that should work for you!

Comment: I don't understand the comment in your code, can you explain a little more? thank you anyway for the other suggestion.

Comment: you used `Vector3.forward`, i was saying maybe try `transform.forward`, since you are trying to rotate it by a dynamic axis

Comment: ok I tried but it doesn't work. I'll try with the `GameObject` parent